# Write variable length strings in single console line

Tags: r

I use RStudio. Within a loop, I want to display in a single console line a string of variable length. I am using `cat()`. If I use `\n`, different lines are written (not what I want):

```
A <- c("AAAAA","BBB","C")
for (i in 1:3){cat(A[i],"\n"); Sys.sleep(1)}
AAAAA 
BBB 
C
```

The use of `\r` works well when names are of the (nearly) same length, but in this case, the result is again not what I want:

```
for (i in 1:3){cat(A[i],"\r"); Sys.sleep(1)}
C B A
```

as it should be only the string "C" when the loop is finished.

I have also tried deleting many spaces with `\b`, but the length difference is large and many times the information is written one line above the current console line.

Is there a simple way to do this? (base R preferred)

Edit: What I want is that, in a single line, first the string "AAAAA" appears. After one second, only the string "BBB" should appear (not "BBB A"). After one second, only the string "C" should appear (not "C B A").

Comment: `cat(A)` or just `A`

Comment: Please show us what your expected output is.

Comment: `for (i in 1:3){cat(A[i],"\t"); Sys.sleep(1)}`

Comment: The answer by @Onyambu does not work as expected. See the Edit.

Comment: The answer by @alistaire does not work as expected. See the Edit.

Comment: So you need to see AAAAA then BBB then C but each printed on the screen alone?

Comment: Yes. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method works if you first pad all the strings to the length of the longest one:

```
A <- c("AAAAA","BBB","C")
max_length = max(nchar(A))
A_filled = stringr::str_pad(A, max_length, side = "right")
for (i in 1:3){cat(A_filled[i],"\r"); Sys.sleep(1)}
```

To pad the strings in base R you can use `sprintf`:

```
max_length = max(nchar(A))
pad_format = paste0("%-", max_length, "s")
A_filled = sprintf(pad_format, A)
```

Comment: Is there not a {base} solution?

Comment: @JASC You needed a single name on the console. This gives two

Answer (score 1):

I tend to believe you want all the strings printed: This is a base R solution

```
 A <- c("AAAAA","BBB","C")
 x <-formatC(A, width = -max(nchar(A)))
 for (i in 1:3){cat("\r",x[i]); Sys.sleep(1)}
```

Comment: Not really, I just want one single name on the console line.

Comment: @JASC Check the edit I think it is what you need. It gives just one single name on the console

Answer (score 0):

I hope, just a simple `cat` works fine.

```
> for (i in 1:3){cat(A[i], " "); Sys.sleep(1)}
AAAAA  BBB  C  

> for (i in 1:3){cat(A[i]); Sys.sleep(1)}
AAAAABBBC
```